# Returning a boolean literal from function as reference

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I have encountered this code during trying to find a bug:

```
int x = 10; // for example

const bool& foo() {
    return x == 10;
}

int bar() {
    bool y = foo(); // error here
}
```

This code block causes a crash when compiled with gcc11.2, while it works correctly and sets y as true in Visual Studio 2019. Both compilers give a warning about returning reference to local variable. I would like to know whether this behaviour is an UB or not. (We fixed this bug by changing bool& to bool)

Edit: I forgot to put const before bool&, sorry about that.

Comment: Why? Return it by value. You're just adding complexity, space, and time.

Comment: Yes it is undefined behaviour. The returned reference refers to a destroyed temporary variable (local to the function, destroyed when the function ends). But what would be the meaning to return it by reference since the variable exists nowhere else ?

Comment: I would question the authors reason for returning a reference to the result of an expression. Can you ask them what they were thinking?

Comment: Why on earth would you use global state nowadays? I hope `x` is's a class field atleast

Comment: [When I try it](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/038f5af604b7f712), it's a hard error: "error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'bool&' to an rvalue of type 'bool'"

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Yes it was a class field, I just tried to simplify code block by writing it as global.

Comment: @user8954499  It is evident that it is a well-defined behavior, is not it? It is the compilers that behave badly and swear.

Comment: @Caleth I forgot to put const before bool&, edited question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is undefined behaviour as you are trying to return a reference on a value whose scope is destroyed once you exit the function.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing the compiler version?
The code shouldn't even compile because it binds a reference to a temporary value. Below output of g++ 7.5
g++  7.5.0

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘bool&’ to an rvalue of type ‘bool’
```

A not const reference does not bind with temporary values.
The compilation problem can be bypassed with a temporary reference

```
const bool& foo() {
    return x == 10;
}
```

but the undefined behavior would remain as it is linked to a temporary value.

**** Update
As suggested I report that the answer referred to an initial question in which the function foo () returned by reference not const  Now the question has been edited to incorporate this. Thanks Yunnosch for the suggestion

Comment: I forgot to put const before bool& in question, so it is compilers that decides whether this code works or not.

Comment: Ah ok. ! if I can suggest a reading in this item by meyers a problem similar to the one posted is faced by thinking about objects instead of elementary types:

Item 21: Don’t try to return a reference when you must return an object. 
from Effective C++ (Meyers)

Comment: I recommend to make clear in this answer, that it refers to a previous version of the question (strictly speaking this is victim of unappreciated "moving target question"). This is a valuable insight which I propose to keep though. Maybe something like "And OP has confirmed by now and edited the question to incorporate this."

Answer (score 1):

`x == 10` is a rvalue not an lvalue, it has not address and you can reference it. If it works under VS 2019 it means that the compiler must surely optimize the code and inline the function or something like that. In debug mode it should not work.